# SailsJS - CORS - The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''

Tags: ajax, apache, nginx, cors, sails.js

I generated a new [sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/get-started) app and created a test API as follows.

```
module.exports = {
     test:function (req, res) {
        return res.ok({success: true});
    },
}
```

The `sails` app is hosted in a standalone local machine with at `192.168.3.208:1337`.

My `CORS` config is as follows.

```
module.exports.cors = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
};
```

When I make a simple `AJAX` call from my local machine (`192.168.3.210`) to the API,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://192.168.3.208:1337/api/test',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I get the following error

> Failed to load http://192.168.3.208:1337/api/test: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''.
>   Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

The html page is hosted with Apache at port 80.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors#?warning for an explanation of why you shouldn’t try to combine `origin: '*' ` with `credentials: true`. I guess during testing you can try setting ``origin: 'http://localhost/' ` and see if that works — and in production, change that `origin` value to whatever real origins you want to allow requests with credentials from. You generally want to avoid allowing credentialed requests from any arbitrary origin.

Comment: Add the `allRoutes: true,` to `cors` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem

```
module.exports.cors = {
  origin: '*', // Required whitelist
  credentials: true,
  headers: ['Authorization', 'content-type', 'user-agent']
};
```